# How to convert batch of rectangular images into square images without cropping?

Tags: imagemagick, image-resizing, imagemagick-convert

Given batch of vertical and horizontal rectangular images :

[image] rect-h.png

[image] rect-v.png

How to convert batch of vertical and horizontal rectangular images into square images ?

So to get same sizes, not-cutted, no disformed :

[image] rect-h-sq.png

[image] rect-v-sq.png

---

I currently use

```
mkdir -p ./temp ./png                                  # create folders to work on copies of data and store final png output
cp ./* ./temp                                          # copies to ./temp, so to word on copies 
for file in ./temp/*.png                               # loop on the [edited] copies in ./temp
do
  keyIn=$(basename "$file" .png)                       # name of the file minus .png
  keyOut=$(basename "$file" .png)-sq.png               # name of the file minus .png, plus .-red.png 
  convert -background none -density 1200 ./temp/$keyIn.png -resize 300x300\! ./png/$keyOut   
done
```

But it fails.

Note: Density is there because I often work with svg as well.

Comment: You cannot do that without either padding or cropping or deforming the images.  Please clarify what you think you want done from these options.

Comment: (In the question : "So to get same sizes, not-cutted, no disformed". Also, i answered the question there https://stackoverflow.com/a/49556858/8992875 )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Padding](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/thumbnails/#pad) works :

```
mkdir -p ./temp ./png                                  # create folders to work on copies of data and store final png output
cp ./* ./temp                                          # copies to ./temp, so to word on copies 
for file in ./temp/*.png                               # loop on the [edited] copies in ./temp
do
  keyIn=$(basename "$file" .png)                       # name of the file minus .png
  keyOut=$(basename "$file" .png)-sq.png               # name of the file minus .png, plus .-red.png 
  convert -background none -density 1200 ./temp/$keyIn.png \
     -thumbnail '300x300>' -background white \
     -gravity center -extent 300x300 -resize 300x300\! ./png/$keyOut   
done
```

Comment: I want the size of the square should be equal to the largest side of the original photo

E.g. 

Original: 500 x 400 => Output:500 x 500
Original: 400 x 600 => Output: 600 x 600

Can you help me?